# Change textfield height on other devices

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm currently working on an iOS application and I'm stuck..

I'm trying to create a "register-form" and I'm designing using "iPhone SE" (Cuz it seems like everyone else is doing so?) And when I'm designing on this device everything seems fine, but when I run the application the textfields seems to be way to small, and not like I want it.

(First image is a design on the iPhone SE)

[image: design1]

(Second image is a design on the iPhone X simulator)
[image: design2]

As you see, it looks very small on the bigger devices ex. iPhone X, XR etc etc. And I've no idea how to make it look the same on all devices. I've added constraints of course, but still not good enough. And If I attach the top constrain to the navigation bar, only that textfield will increase size. (Which is pretty damn much)

One question: Is it required to program my application to ALL iPhone devices? or is it enough with just iPhone 7-iPhoneX? Or do I need to make it good on iPhone 4 etc?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create `UIStackView` with Distribution **Fill Equally**, certain spacing between views and set stack view's frame/constraints.

[image]

Then add these `UITextField`s to this stack view.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use tableView and inside that use xib cell with textfield and reuse it and give the cell a height with respect to the uiscreen example:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return (0.1*UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

    }
```